# Instalation of Redmine on Debian Jessie from packages with mysql and nginx

Tags: debian, redmine

My goal is instalation redmine from jessie packages for simplify future upgrades. I would like to use mysql and nginx. On Ruby side I prefer to use unicorn or other simple server.
I have tried to follow manuals available in the net but they do not cover my configuration or are not actual or not base on debian packages.
Is it possible at all and someone has got environment similar to my description or I would rather leave my idea?

Comment: Check the guides on redmine.org. However I would recommend installation of Redmine under some user account, and through RVM, and from SVN. So your updates won't break your Redmine... Unicorn, or puma are good...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Aleksander comment. Based on my testing it is much more easiest to install/configure redmine as user application (within /home dir) from sources and using gem/bundle tools. Finally I have decided to use puma instead of unicorn and nginx as reverse proxy for puma. 
Only ruby and gem packages has been installed from apt-get. 
Init scripts from puma git has not been compatible with my Debian Jessie installation. I do not know why and I have decided to run puma directly as user service without systemctl support.